# Use Scrollview like MapView ,with scroll and zoom option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, scroll, zooming

I have some map images and i want that i can scroll that images and i can zoom that images.
Like , MKMapView we can zoom images and the placeMark will remains as it is (it would not zoom).
same thing i want to do without  MKMapView with my static images.with the help of scrollview or any other.

is it possible ?,is there any code available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are looking for is called `CATiledLayer`. Be warned, it is not trivial. Try reading [Matt Gallagher's excellent write up](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/).